# Python print the sentences from the corpus containing the word

Tags: python

I'm asked to print the sentences from the corpus containing the word(s) with the greatest number of distinct tags. I already got the top 6 words with most distinct tags (5 tags). My questions are:

1. I don't know how to get the words without using "len(cfd[key])>4"? Because I've tried using max() function but it doesn't work.
2. I want to print the sentences that include these words. But it prints all sentences that include the non-exact words. For example, I just want to print sentences included only EXACT word: "round", but the code also print the sentences that included "around" (because "round" is part of "around"). What do I have to add?

This is my code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
from nltk.probability import ConditionalFreqDist
from nltk.corpus import*
from nltk.book import*
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

import string
import re
cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist((word,tag) for (word, tag) in 
brown.tagged_words(tagset='universal'))
homographs = [(key, len(cfd[key])) for key in cfd.keys() if len(cfd[key])>4]
words = [key for key in cfd.keys() if len(cfd[key])>4]
print("Word(s) with the greatest number of distinct tags:", homographs)
print("List of sentences containing the word: ")
txt = brown.sents()
for sentence in txt:
    if list(set(words) & set(sentence)):
        result = "".join([" "+i if not i.startswith("'") and i not in string.punctuation else i for i in sentence]).strip()
        print(result)
```

Anyone can help me, how to solve these problems? Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Welcome to code review where we review working code and provide suggestions on how the code can be improved. Unfortunately this question is off-topic because the code isn't working.

Comment: @pacmaninbw thank you, I already edited and improved some code. Please take a look :)

Comment: The code still doesn't work according to specification, does it? Feel free to come back once it does.

Comment: thank you, I forgot to add the last line into the loop. I hope now it's working @Mast